# grails springSecurityService.principal.id creates null exception instead of redirecting to login page

Tags: grails, spring-security

This error happens periodically during my development.  Given a controller:

```
class AccountController {
   def index() {
      User user = User.load(springSecurityService.principal.id)
      //do something
   }

   ....
}
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - MissingPropertyException occurred when processing request: [GET] /account/index
No such property: id for class: java.lang.String. Stacktrace follows:
Message: No such property: id for class: java.lang.String
```

The issue is my user is no longer logged in so the session is not valid.  The springSecurityService.principal is null so the id cannot be found.

However I thought this was something springsecurity was supposed to handle be default before my controller action was ever reached?  Should it not realize the session timed-out and redirect to the login page?  Maybe I don't have something configured correctly.  I really don't want to add a check in every controller/action to see if the principal is valid before doing some work.

I'm using grails 2.2.4 and spring security core plugin 1.2.7.3, and spring security ui 0.2

Comment: Where is the rule defined that says what roles are required for this action?

Comment: Some staff at work have a similar problem (almost always, rather than periodically)... any time a controller is hot-recompiled `principal` is null. They replace `principal.username` with a string (`bob` for example) so that they can get some development work done.

Comment: Burt - the controller did not have any secured annotation, and the controller was not defined in interceptUrlMap in Config.groovy.  Does that sound like the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you not add the `@Secured` annotation to the controller or the action, nor add the URL to the requestmap configured within `Config.groovy` or requestmap instances in the database your controller isn't secured. Have a look at the [docs](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual.1273/guide/5%20Configuring%20Request%20Mappings%20to%20Secure%20URLs.html) for further informations about the configuration of secured URLs.

Due to the fact that the controller isn't secured, the user wouldn't be redirected to the login page if he isn't logged in.

If the user is authenticated `springSecurityService.principal` returns an instance of `GrailsUser`. If the session is timed out (the user isn't authenticated) the name of the anonymous user name will be returned (`'anonymousUser'` by default). This is the reason for your `Exception` due to the `String` `'anonymousUser'` has no property `id`.

To solve your issue configure the security constraints for your controller according to your needs and the anonymous user will be redirected to the login page.

To get the currently loggin in user you could simply use `springSecurityService.currentUser` ...

Hope that helps.